# Outlining photo content (like a colouring book)

Tags: color, gimp

I am trying to make a full color photo into just a black outline to be printed and colored in by hand, basically just making coloring pages off of full color photos. I just installed gimp, but cannot figure it out. If there is a better program to use, I would gladly use it. Any help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to GD.SE!

To get the effect that you are looking for you could use the [photocopy filter](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-photocopy.html) in Gimp.

You get to this filter via Filters → Artistic → Photocopy.

A filter window will then pop up with sliders that change the value of the mask radius, the sharpness, percentage of black and percentage of white. This window has a nifty preview box so before you commit any changes you can have a look at how your photo is doing.

These settings will differ depending on your photo but with the preview box there is plenty of room for trial and error and you will quickly find settings that suit your image.

[Here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1125925?start=0&tstart=0) is also a Photoshop tutorial for the same filter is you have access to it.

Best of luck!

Comment: See also the Treshold

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what Jenna said.

I would then use a magic wand tool to select all the white area's and remove them so its a true #fff (white) backdrop.

If you was to then to apply a color overlay to the black outline of #000 (Black) this would make it a true b/w image.